# Should you really make a long-time user read through the tour page to get a badge every time that person joins a new site?

Tags: discussion, badges, tour

I think if you have enough reputation to get the association bonus (i.e. >200 rep) you should be awarded the "read the tour" badge automatically. That way, you need not worry about buffing your bronze badge count by one by "reading" the tour page every time you join a new community.

Comment: Is it really that big of a struggle for you to click on "tour" and scroll down the page? FWP.

Comment: @Catija It takes 10 seconds.





...that's alot.

Comment: Wow... takes me two.

Comment: Takes me 0.88 seconds!

Comment: @JamesLu "it takes 10 seconds" Ok, to be kind/fair, let's say it takes *twice* as long as you claim, so 20 seconds. Are you really saying "*20 seconds is way too long a time spent to earn a badge*". All you have to do is a very simple action for 20 seconds....and you get a badge...this is the easiest badge you will ever earn. In fact, given the aforementioned, I'd be inclined to make it *harder* for seasoned users (no change for new users)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another thing is that you actually should read the some sections of the tour of a new site you are joining, especially the uppermost few sentences and what is on- and off-topic. If you don't read that, you might end up asking a Question at the wrong site.

So no, I am strongly against giving the badge just away like this. If you have to scroll through the tour you have a little chance of at least reading the  uppermost few sentences.

Comment: This is by far the best answer here. What's on- and off-topic for various sites around the network is widely different, and you should definitely be looking through it for every site you first visit because some are not so clear-cut and contain customized information on that page. We can't assume just because you have an association bonus that you know the scope of every site, so awarding the badge on every site makes no sense.

Answer (score 22):

I'm somewhat surprised that someone who is familiar enough with Stack Exchange to get the association bonus would bother "buffing" their bronze badge counts. However, just giving people things removes any value they have - there's no point having something if it's worthless.

If people do want to increase the number of bronze badges they have in this way then there's little point bespoking code to help them - it only takes a few seconds to scroll down the page.

Comment: 2 seconds * millions of people = several years of human time that could've gone to cancer research

Answer (score 17):

> Should you really make a long-time user read through the tour page to
>   get a badge every time that person joins a new site?

Yes, because that's what is required to earn the badge.

If someone has visited the site for 99 days consecutively, should we just give them the "fanatic" badge, because, well, they've done pretty much all of the requirements, so what's one more day?

One more day is the *specifics* of what is *required* to earn that badge.
Reading the tour page is the specifics of what is required to earn the "informed" badge.

Badges are designed to encourage specific behaviours.
The "informed" badge is designed to encourage new users to read the tour page, not earn rep on sites. And having *both* options to earn the badge makes no sense.

> I think if you have enough reputation to get the association bonus
>   (i.e. >200 rep) you should be awarded the "read the tour" badge
>   automatically

Why does your rep have any bearing on earning a non-rep related badge which has a specific requirement - read the tour page, not earn 200 rep.

> That way, you need not worry about buffing your bronze badge count by
>   one by "reading" the tour page every time you join a new community.

You are seeing the badges in the wrong light. They're not there to be given to you based some "I've been here years" or whatever, you *earn* them by doing the specific requirements.

If you don't need to read the tour page, don't, and you wont get the badge.
If you want the badge, even if you don't need to read the tour page, then read the tour page and get the badge.

It's fine if you're interested in your total badge count, but it's not exactly hard to read the tour page to get the badge.