# I have a feeling that I am discouraged from expressing my opinion

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

[Here's the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263444/should-you-really-make-a-long-time-user-read-through-the-tour-page-to-get-a-badg)

I agree with those who answered. They are correct.

However, after expressing my opinion and asking others for theirs, I lost 21 reputation.

We are encouraged to delete down-voted questions because it restores reputation (why else would you do so?)

But then, there's this picture:

[image: Here]

Ouch.

My point here is the downvotes.

Comment: It seems like you simply care way too much about the stats in your user card.  Worry more about providing quality content, and improving the site as a resource, and less about how much rep or how many badges you have.  If you strive to provide quality content, the recognition will follow.  If you strive for the recognition at the expense of actually making positive contributions, things won't turn out well, long term.

Comment: I don't understand this. Its not about question deletion, its about opinion expression.

Comment: Also the fact that it was DOWNVOTED.

Comment: I'm well aware of that.  You're stating that you're unwilling to express your opinion if it results in you losing a few dozen rep.  I'm telling you that you shouldn't care so much about a few dozen rep that you would let it prevent you from expressing an opinion you think is valuable.  It should of course make you question if that opinion is in fact valuable.

Comment: Wait, it was downvoted?  I though you were complaining about the fact that it was upvoted.  In that case....

Comment: It is valuable that this website can save me hours of time and that this may lead to a "Your recent questions have not been accepted very well..."

Comment: I find it unlikely that meta.SE is a site that can save you hours of time.

Comment: Regarding the edit, what about the downvotes? And if you only ask about the downvotes, how that warning you posted a screenshot of is related?

Answer (score 10):

First, you can't delete it since it has upvoted answers.

Second, voting on Meta is a little different. You can gain or lose a lot for a simple question. On Meta, we express our agreement or disagreement with our votes. And since you propose a change, the best way to know if the community agrees is to let them vote.

This point is often learned by your first questions on Meta. Next time you will be thinking a lot more about the complications a proposal might have, the pros and cons. And even then sometimes we fail to do a proposal that sticks.

Bottom line is: don't let these votes disappoint you. Your internet are not worth that much. Learn from it.

Comment: But I might get banned for it. Globally. Ex. the computer determined bans uncontrolled by mods

Comment: @CrazyPython It's *very* hard to get question banned on meta.SE.  You'd have to provide a *lot* of *extremely* poorly received content to actually earn yourself a question ban, much more so than what it takes on normal sites.  It's only actually happened a handful of times.

Comment: @CrazyPython Also, it doesn't trigger a global question block. If you managed to trigger it, you'd only be blocked from asking here on Meta SE.